# Display output on other PHP file

Tags: php, html, css

I have a form in index.php and it is processed in my process.php. I wanted to hide the form in index.php after submit and change it into the confirmation message. But, my code's not working how i wanted it to work. Here's my code:

This is my index.php(the session counter is working but it is staying on the form after clicking submit):

```
<?php session_start();?>
<html>
    <body>
        <main>
        <?php 
                if(isset($_POST['name_entered'])){
                    if($_SESSION['counter'] <= 10 && $_SESSION['counter'] > 0) {
                        //$_SESSION['counter'] = $_SESSION['counter'] + 1;
                        ?>
                        <h2>Welcome Customer!</h2>
                        <p>We are giving away <span class="bold_text">free coupons</span> as token of appreciation</p>
                        <section>
                            <h4>50% discount</h4>
                            <h1 id="random_num"><?= rand(1000000,9999999);?></h1>
                            <form action="process.php" method="post">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn1" name="reset_btn" value="Reset Count">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn2" name="claim_again_btn" value="Claim Again">
                            </form>
                        </section>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        <h2>Welcome Customer!</h2>
                        <p>We are giving away <span class="bold_text">free coupons</span> as token of appreciation</p>
                        <section>
                            <h3>Sorry!</h3>
                            <h1>Unavailable!</h1>
                            <form action="process.php" method="post">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn1" value="Reset Count" name="reset_btn">
                            </form>
                        </section>
    <?php 
                    }
                } else { ?>
                    <h2>Welcome Customer!</h2>
                    <div class="first_message">
                    <p>We are giving away <span class="bold_text">free coupons</span> as token of appreciation for first <?= $_SESSION['counter'] ?> customer(s)</p>
                    <form action="process.php" method="post">
                        <label for="name">Kindly type your name: </label>
                        <input type="text" id="name" name="name_entered">
                        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
                    </form>
                </div>
                <?php }
                ?>   
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my process.php:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    
    if(!isset($_SESSION['counter'])){
        $_SESSION['counter'] = 10;
        
    } else {
        $_SESSION['counter'] = $_SESSION['counter'] - 1;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['reset_btn'])){
        $_SESSION['counter'] = 10;
    }

    header("Location: index.php");
    ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$_POST['name_entered']` will not be triggered when you redirect to the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After redirect with header() function you do not have anything in $_POST anymore. In this case access to posted values you have only in process.php. You can save your posted values in $_SESSION and check those in index.php